# /i18n/setlang/ HTTP/1.1 302 неработает переключение языков set_language

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, i18n

Настройки:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'

LANGUAGES = (
    ('ru', _('Russian')),
    ('en', _('English')),
)

LOCALE_PATHS = (
    project_dir + "/apps/locale",
)

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
...
```

В навбар встроил код:

```
    <form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ redirect_to }}">
        <select name="language">
            {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
            {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
            {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
            {% for language in languages %}
                <option value="{{ language.code }}"{% if language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE %} selected{% endif %}>
                    {{ language.name_local }} ({{ language.code }})
                </option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Go">
    </form>
```

сгенерировал локали, перевел, и скомпилировал:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Страница просто обновляется при попытке изменения языка, и язык не меняется.
В консоли выводит при этом:
[29/Mar/2019 12:24:27] "POST /i18n/setlang/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[29/Mar/2019 12:24:27] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2389

Comment: `302 Found, 302 Moved Temporarily — запрошенный документ временно доступен по другому URI, указанному в заголовке в поле Location. Этот код может быть использован, например, при управляемом сервером согласовании содержимого. Некоторые[какие?] клиенты некорректно ведут себя при обработке данного кода. Введено в HTTP/1.0.`

Comment: тем не менее непонятно почему не срабатывает локализация